# How to remove disabled attribute from button if checked box is true?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a bunch of checkbox items. When I click the checkbox, I want the disabled attribute to be removed from the button, allowing the button to be clicked and a total displayed.

I've attached `calcButton.removeAttribute('disabled');` to the conditional, but it's not removing the `disabled` attribute from the button.

```js
var calcButton = document.getElementById("calcButton");

if (document.getElementById("total")) {
  calcTotal();
}

function calcTotal() {
  var itemTotal = 0;
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    if (items[i].checked) {
      itemTotal += items[i].value * 1;
      calcButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is:  $" + itemTotal + ".00";
  }
}

var payOptions = document.getElementById('payOpts');
if (calcButton.addEventListener) {
  calcButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);

} else if (calcButton.attachEvent) {
  calcButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
}

calcButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  payOptions.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form label {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

button {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="item1" class="container">Hamburger ($5.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item1" value="5">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item2" class="container">Hotdog ($5.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item2" value="5">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item3" class="container">Jumbo Hotdog ($7.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item3" value="7">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item4" class="container">Corndog ($4.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item4" value="4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item5" class="container">Chicken Fingers ($6.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item5" value="5">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item6" class="container">Nachos ($4.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item6" value="4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item7" class="container">French Fries ($3.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item7" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item8" class="container">Soft Pretzel ($3.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item8" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item9" class="container">Small Drink ($2.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item9" value="2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item10" class="container">Large Drink ($4.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item10" value="4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item11" class="container">Bottled Water ($3.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item11" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <p id="total" class="priceInfo"></p>
  <button type="button" id="calcButton" disabled="disabled">Pay me this!</button>

  <div class="pay-options" id="payOpts" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching the onclick on the disabled calcButton, and that doesn't work as it's disabled and can't enabled itself.

`calcTotal` is also called at the beginning, but there aren't options selected so the calcbutton won't be enabled also

See this example. If have added another button to show that `removeAttribute` is working well:

```js
   var calcButton = document.getElementById("calcButton");

if (document.getElementById("total")) {
  calcTotal();
}

function calcTotal() {
  var itemTotal = 0;
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    if (items[i].checked) {
      itemTotal += items[i].value * 1;
      calcButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is:  $" + itemTotal + ".00";
  }
}

var payOptions = document.getElementById('payOpts');
if (calcButton.addEventListener) {
  calcButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);

} else if (calcButton.attachEvent) {
  calcButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
}

document.getElementById("realCalcButton").addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
calcButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  payOptions.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form label {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

button {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="item1" class="container">Hamburger ($5.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item1" value="5">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item2" class="container">Hotdog ($5.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item2" value="5">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item3" class="container">Jumbo Hotdog ($7.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item3" value="7">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item4" class="container">Corndog ($4.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item4" value="4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item5" class="container">Chicken Fingers ($6.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item5" value="5">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item6" class="container">Nachos ($4.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item6" value="4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item7" class="container">French Fries ($3.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item7" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item8" class="container">Soft Pretzel ($3.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item8" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item9" class="container">Small Drink ($2.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item9" value="2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item10" class="container">Large Drink ($4.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item10" value="4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label for="item11" class="container">Bottled Water ($3.00)
    <input type="checkbox" id="item11" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <p id="total" class="priceInfo"></p>
  <button type="button" id="realCalcButton">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="calcButton" disabled="disabled">Pay me this!</button>


  <div class="pay-options" id="payOpts" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
  </div>
</form>
```